# Drop duplicate values in each list in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a long list of lists that looks like:

```
mylist = [['1', 24, 'A', 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C', 'B']]
```

I want drop any duplicate values after the first two positions in each list, so for `['1', 24, 'A', 'A']`, ignore positions `1` and `24`, then consider the rest of positions to see if there are duplicates. For this list, I want output `['1', 24, 'A']`. The list lengths are variable, anywhere from 3 to 8 items long.

Full desired output is:

```
output = [['1', 24, 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C']]
```

The order within each list is important, but not the overall order of all the lists in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.OrdederDict` to remove duplicates. It will maintain the order of elements.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mylist = [['1', 24, 'A', 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C', 'B']]
[[a,b, *list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(c))] for a,b,*c in mylist]
```

This will give output

```
[['1', 24, 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C']]
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in comments by `Mykola Zotko`, In python 3.7 you can safely use `dict` as well!

```
[[a,b, *list(dict.fromkeys(c))] for a,b,*c in mylist]
```

Comment: In Python 3.7 dict is ordered by default: `dict.fromkeys()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use unpacking with a set:

```
mylist = [['1', 24, 'A', 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C', 'B']]
new_list = [[a, b, *[h for i, h in enumerate(c) if h not in c[:i]]] for a, b, *c in mylist]
```

Output:

```
[['1', 24, 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: The original answer with `set()` seems to preserve the order just fine, is that unexpected?

Comment: @Liquidity That is merely a coincidence, as `set` automatically returns a  *sorted* result. It just so happens that your example input contains trailing values that are already sorted.

Comment: Highly inefficient. You create a new list for each element in c. Plus the operator `in` works  not so fast with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Install the ordered_set from [here](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/)

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet
mylist = [['1', 24, 'A', 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C', 'B']]
for i in range (len(mylist)): mylist[i] = list(OrderedSet(mylist[i]))
print(mylist)
```

The output will be

> [['1', 24, 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C']]

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the solution of Ajax1234. You can use a small helper function to filter the rest of elements. The operator `in` works much faster with sets than with lists:

```
mylist = [['1', 24, 'A', 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C', 'B']]

def filt(l):
    s = set()
    for i in l:
        if i not in s:
            s.update(i)
            yield i

l = [[i, j, *filt(k)] for i, j, *k in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [['1', 24, 'A', 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'B', 'C', 'B']]
result = [x[0:2] + list(set(x[2:])) for x in mylist]
print(result)
```

output:

```
[['1', 24, 'A'], ['1', 35, 'A', 'B'], ['2', 12, 'C', 'B']]
```